# List collection in C# where internal representation only grows?

Tags: c#, arrays, collections

One of the reasons List's are generally good for adding and removing items is that the internal data representation is allocated larger than needed to reduce the number of reallocations.

Is there a way to make an instance of this class (or another similar class) to grow as needed by a decent chunk size, but to prevent reducing the size of the internal array?

Comment: Would implementing  `IList` and designing the behavior you want be overkill?

Comment: This is probably an overkill not because this is some additional code, but because List implementation is highly efficient (native code) and this might be hard to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware that the internal array ever reduces in size automatically (you can use `TrimExcess` to manually reduce it).  `List<T>` always increases capacity doubling the size of the internal array whenever it runs out of space.  You could write a wrapper class that increases the `Capacity` however you want if you don't like the built-in policy.

Comment: Awesome! so I guess the standard implementation already achieves what I am after. I am using the Mono runtime, but I suspect that the list implementation will work in much the same way.

Comment: Yep, basically the same in Mono: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/List.cs#L100